# File Drop Automation can't work

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, fileupload

I have an automation triggered by File Drop. when the file is dropped , it will be imported to a staging data extention(overwrite).
now here is an odd thing: when I upload a file name as
"AAA_TEST_%%Year%%%%Month%%%%Day%%_%%Hour%%.csv" , it can trigger the automation, and automation runs successfully. However, the data in the staging DE still can't be overwrite and still previous data ,seems the import activity doesn't work.
I have tried many times but still keep failing.
[image]

Comment: Can you share the whole automation and the import activity? does the import work correctly?

Comment: Add your email to receive the notifications from the Import Activity - it will send you a summary each time the import runs and you will get all the details of what happened and if there were any errors. Without it, it's impossible to troubleshoot. Once you have those details, please include them in your original question.

Comment: As @SebOB pointed out this is how your import activity is configured and not the file drop trigger

Comment: Did you manage to try out my suggested solution?

Answer (score 0):

You should replace your personalisation string with %%BASEFILENAME_FROM_TRIGGER%%.csv - this is IMHO the most solid solution, as you avoid issues with time zones etc. you can get [more details here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_substitution_strings_example.htm&type=5)